# Exposing application deployed on kubernetes cluster in front of Bigip

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, big-ip

We have an application that is deployed to a Kubernetes cluster on a baremetal system. I have exposed the service as NodePort. We need to expose the service to the outside world using a domain name myapp.example.com. We have created the necessary DNS mapping and we have configured our VIP in our Bigip Loadbalancer. I would like to know what ingress solution we need to implement? Is it from the Nginx/Kubernetes or the Bigip controller? Will Nginx/Kubernetes Nginx controller support Bigip and how do we need to expose the ingress-nginx? is it type LB or Nodeport?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Bigip that much but I found that they have a [controller for kubernetes](https://clouddocs.f5.com/containers/v2/kubernetes/).

But I think the simplest way if you have Bigip Loadbalancer already setup and a k8s cluster running then just create the NodePort service for the pod that you want to expose and get the node port number of that service (lets assume 30001). This port is now open and can be used to communicate to the service inside the K8s using the Node's IP. Now configure the Bigip Loadbalancer pool to forward all the incoming traffic to < Node's IP >:30001.

All this is theory from what I know about k8s and how it works. Give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh. The problem is we have couple of microservices and we have to open the port from Bigip to the Node pool address for each application. Our security team wont approve it hence we want to use a ingress solution

Comment: You can see how to configure ingress on bare-metal server here https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#over-a-nodeport-service

Comment: But if I where you I would have created a nginx pod, exposed it using node port service and and create nginx conf to route traffic to all my microservices. Just because I know nginx better and it's easy for me to write nginx conf, rather then configuring ingress.